# Saturating images onclick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple interface that includes 4 icons (images) positioned horizontally that serve more or less as a menu. When 1 of the 4 icons are clicked, that particular icon should stay highlighted (increased saturation), while losing its highlight when one of the others are clicked, and so forth. The html markup looks as follows:

```
<ul>
        <li><img onclick="saturate()" src="../images/efficiency.png" alt="efficiency"/></li>
        <li><img onclick="saturate()" src="../images/educated_team.png"></li>
        <li><img onclick="saturate()" src="../images/profitable_options.png"></li>
        <li><img onclick="saturate()" src="../images/strategic_solutions.png"></li>

</ul>
```

Each icon has been equipped with an onclick method to call my javascript function, and none of them have an id or a class since i am grabbing them using

`document.getElementsByTagName('li');`

Now, my current javascript function looks like this:

```
function saturate() {
    var sat = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

     for(var i = 0; i < sat.length; i = i + 1) {
     sat[i].style.webkitFilter = 'saturate(180%)';
}}
```

I was told that a for loop was necessary to use since getElementsByTagName returns an array. My problem for now is that when one of the icons are clicked, all of them are highlighted. Additionally, i need a way for the saturation to go back to normal when the icon is clicked a second time.
I desire to avoid the use of jQuery since i'm still in the learning phase.

What i basically want to know, is how can i make a proper function that allows for just a single one of the icons to be highlighted at a time when clicked, and how do i remove same highlight when clicking on the icon once more?

I should mention that i have styled the images in a seperate CSS file, where they have been set to have a default saturation of 100%.

I'm new to this forum, i appologize for any inconveniences.

Comment: As a side comment, it would be beneficial (more maintainable, better practice) for you to start moving away from inline event registration and move toward setting up event listeners. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

> how can i make a proper function that allows for just a single one of the icons to be highlighted at a time when clicked?

Like this:

```
...
<li><img id="EducatedTeam" onclick="saturate('EducatedTeam')" src="../images/educated_team.png"></li>
...
```

And:

```
function saturate(id) {
  var img = document.getElementById(id);
  img.style.webkitFilter = 'saturate(180%)';
}
```

Basically, you need to connect each `img` element to a specific handler. You could do this by binding to all `img` tags and using `this` to act on only the changed elements, or by assigning IDs to each and passing that along, as I've shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bit of css classes on the LI's to indicate saturation.

```
.sat{
 -webkit-filter: saturate(180%);
}

function saturate()
{
  var parentUl = this.parentNode.parentNode; //this sets you at the ul
  var lis = parentUl.getElementsByTagName("li");
  // clear the class
  for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
  {
     lis[i].className = "";
  }
  //set the one you want
  this.parentNode.className='sat';
}
```

If you are using IE9+ you can simply exchange the `getElementsByTagName` for `getElementsByClassName` and get a smaller collection.